# Getting multilevel counts

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the number of downlines (refferals brought by a user) of each user stored in a database such as this:

```
       ------------------------------------
           + UserID      +  refferedby
       ------------------------------------
       l    23           l      80
       l    25           l      23  
       l    36           l      25
       l    75           l      36
       l    98           l      75
       l    24           l      98
       l    209          l      24
```

The total referral brought by 25 should be : 23, 80, 36,75,98,24,204

Pseudode:

```
function getalldownlines(){
    // Get all users id  and store in array
    // loop through the array to get each users total downlines by calling function get_all()
}

function  get_all(){
    // get all users downline and downlines brought by user to the last user
    // it should keep count each and every one of them
    return $count;
}
```

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Do you want to return the total number, or the actual records?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: i want the total number and also the level to the first user

Comment: what do you mean with the level to the first user?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here.

The first and obvious would be to create a recursive function in PHP which returns the referrals from one user and then calls itself again with each of them.

The other option is doing it directly in SQL. <strike>MySQL for example supports recursion, but some others RDBMS don't. I'm not sure if the recursion syntax is supported in standard SQL.</strike>

**Update**: Seems I was wrong. MySQL doesn't support recursive queries; PostgreSQL, Firebird and MS Sql Server do, among others.

The following pseudocode needs completion. My PHP-fu is a bit rusty:

```
function getalldownlines()
{
    $sqlcmd = "SELECT UserID FROM table";

    // fill array $arr with data from SQL

    foreach ($id in $arr)
    {
        $count = get_all($id);
        $numreferreds[$id] = $count;
    }
}
```

---

```
function get_all($id)
{
    $sqlcmd = "SELECT referredby FROM table WHERE UserId='$id'";

    $count = 0;

    // fill array $arr with data from SQL

    foreach ($referred in $arr)
    {
        $count += get_all($referred);
    }

    return $count;
}
```